# change text size of checkbox via c# code

Tags: c#, winforms

I create many checkboxes dynamically in c# ( windows forms ). I want to assign the sizes of the checkboxes' texts. But I couldn't find a way. I want something like that :

```
CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[ff.documentColumnCount];     
chk[i].Font.Size = 8.5; // but of course this line doesn't work
```

what can I do about this,thanks for helping..

Comment: -1 If you have two independent code segments, do not use them in one code block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
chk[i].Font = new Font(chk[i].Font.FontFamily, 8.5f);
```

Comment: thanks :)
 right solution :chk[i].Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 8.5f);

Comment: array of checkoxes is not initialized

Comment: I assumed that the code posted above was just an illustration of what he wanted to do, not the complete code, since he explicitly asked for setting the size of the checkboxes, not how to create and initialize an array of them.

Answer (score 2):

The Font property is immutable (see [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.font.aspx)). You have to assign the Font property a new instance of the Font class with the properties that you want.

```
chk[i].Font = new Font( chk[i].Font.FontFamily, 8.5 );
```

Comment: chk[i] in a right part will raise `NullReferenceException` exception, because chk[i] is null

Comment: @Artur - I think you're taking the small code snippet too literally.  I assume that it's just an example of what is being tried, not the exact code.

Comment: sometimes there are such a questions, where is no way to distinguish whether  the author made a mistake or just omitted a valuable piece of code

Comment: @ArturMustafin fine, I can see where you might have interpreted it differently. Given that the code won't even compile (Size is a read-only property), assuming the problem is a NullReferenceException is a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialized the array. You just declared that there is an array `chk` of size `ff.DocumentCount`

Try fix it to the following:

```
CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[ff.documentColumnCount];     
for(int i=0; i < ff.documentColumnCount; i++)
{
    chk[i] = new CheckBox() { Location = new Point(0, i * 50), Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8.5f) };
}
```

Comment: You have to supply the size in the constructor. Size is a readonly property on System.Drawing.Font.